# C++ - Exception handling

Tags: exception

I'm learning exception handling in C++. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class point{
private:
    float x, y;
public:
    enum Error{
    negative_coordinates,
    };
    point();
    point(float, float);
    ~point();
    float return_x();
    float return_y();
};

point::point(){
}

point::point(float a, float b){
    if(x < 0 && y < 0){
    throw negative_coordinates;
    }
    else{
    x = a;
    y = b;
    }
}

point::~point(){
}

float point::return_x(){
    return x;
}

float point::return_y(){
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    try{
    float x, y;
    cout << "Enter coordinates of some point: " << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;
    if(x < 0 && y < 0){
    throw (0);
    }
    }
    catch(point::Error e){
    const char * message [] = {"You entered negative coordinates"};
    cout << "" << message[e] << endl;
    }
}
```

If I put two negative values I got this:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 5.420 s
Press any key to continue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You throw an 'int' when you enter two negative values, but you catch a point. The types of your throw and catch need to be the same. If I change: catch(point::Error e) to catch(int e), the program runs fine.

As per: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/